# Is it bad practice to let web filter chain access to rest API

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, microservices, spring-webflux

I'm implementing a microservices architecture where I have three services: Project, User, and Product. A user may be an owner or participant of a project. When a user is going to perform an action on the Product service, I have to check whether the user has permission on the project where the product resides. So, I came up with a solution: I created a WebFilter that checks whether a user has permission on the requested project by querying data from the Project service.

```
class ProjectAuthorizationFilter: WebFilter {

    companion object {
        const val PROJECT_HEADER = "X-Project-Id"
    }

    private lateinit var projectOperations: ProjectOperations

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        return exchange.getPrincipal<UserDetails>()
            .flatMap { projectOperations.getPermittedProject(it.userId) }
            .filter { permitted_project ->
                permitted_project.any { it == exchange.request.headers.getOrDefault(PROJECT_HEADER, null) }
            }
            .switchIfEmpty(deniedAccess())
            .flatMap { chain.filter(exchange) }
    }

}
```

I wonder if this is a decent solution or not to let a web filter chain query data from other services and use it to validate.

Comment: Spring Security can do this for you using an `@PreAuthorize`, instead of building your own.

Comment: @M.Deinum but I need to query the data from another microservice. does that work too? using PreAuthorize

Comment: You can call methods in SpEL like anything else and do the comparison. You would call `@projectOperations.getPermittedProject` which would call the method on the given bean and can use for comparison. If it wouldn't be possible to integrate you would need a filter for each and every rule, now that wouldn't be a very well thought of security solution imho (nor to mention the performance of that).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that works. btw is it a common approach to use query for authorization in microservices architecture. I tried searching on google but didn't find how to properly handle it.

Comment: you havn't really disclosed what kind of authentication you are using. Because as i can see is that when we enter your custom filter, we seem to have a authenticated principal already, but this principal doesn't seem to have any grantedAuthorities. Thats why you need to do a lookup. So what kind of authentication method are you using? opague token, jwt, cookie session etc

Comment: @Toerktumlare I use Jwt which has userId on the payload. I use the userId for querying permission of a user on the project service.

Comment: why dont you put the authorities in the jwt, or the scopes in the jwt?

Comment: @Toerktumlare you mean to add the projectId to the authorities where a user has permission? that strategy would also be effective, however as project members can change regularly, I would need to refresh the token to keep it up to date.

Comment: no, what i mean is that when the user logs in, you do a pwd check, and before you create(issue) the JWT, you fetch his permissions, from somewhere, and stick them into the JWT. you probably need to read up a bit on JWT claims, and roles. Here you can read https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: @Toerktumlare I understand now, but this approach would require the client to refresh their token when a permission has been changed on the project, isn't? For example, let's say I am a participant in the project and I obtain an access token with a 30-minute lifetime. Then, if the owner changes my permission so that I am no longer a participant in the project, I would still be able to access the project for 30 minutes since I obtained the access token before the permission change occurred.

Comment: Oh but I can revoke the token when the owner changes the permission right?

Comment: there are several user cases that can be solved differently. Revoking a token is one thing, how often do you add remove permissions? usually when the calling service gets a 401 back it tries to renew the token once... if it has new permissions then, the second try will work.

Comment: this is turning into a discussion which i dont like. You should read up on the different oauth2 flows, and decide which flow works best for you. Because now, you are building a custom security solution, which is bad practice. there are many many resources out there that will explain oauth2s multiple different auth flows on the internet.